# Why does Activity dies after starting a Service?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I wonder why this is happening. My MainActivity starts a service and passes itself to the service so the service can call one of the MainActivity's methods with the data it obtained (I'm fully aware that that's not the way things should be done). However, when this method is called, every field in the Activity is null and trying to call `findViewById()` results in `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference`.

This means the Activity died, but how come? The Activity's lifecycle is not over. Why did the garbage collector took it away?

Please, take a look at the code:

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Serializable{

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private MyAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Servicio.class);
        intent.putExtra("ACTIVITY", this);
        startService(intent);
    }

    public void loadList(List<Data>){
        mList = (LinkedList<Data> dataList;

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) this.findViewById(R.id.rv);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, mList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private Thread mThread;
    private Activity mActivity;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                execute();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
        mActivity = (Activity) intent.getSerializableExtra("ACTIVITY");
        mThread.start();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public void execute(){
        dataObtained = doStuff();
        ((MainActivity) mActivity).loadList(dataObtained);
    }
}
```

However, if I use `sendBroadcast()` in the service to send back the data and retrieve it in the Activity by registering a BroadcastReceiver in it, the Activity remains fully operational and I can call `findViewById()`. How? When did the lifecycle ended before but not in this case?

Comment: i think it has to do with thread issues but i'm not sure. I don't have a solution but, if you want to keep things that way, its better to move the activity reference to an application class, and nullify it in onStop and bind the reference in onStart. Passing activity references in intents is bad idea. EDIT: i dont think you can serialize activities tho, even tho its just a reference

Comment: Using intents is a bad idea on the whole, hahahaha. I just want to know the reason; I'm never going to code like this for real.

Comment: I don't know too =( Have you verified that this ---mActivity = (Activity) intent.getSerializableExtra("ACTIVITY")  --- actually works ? i mean does it give anything but null?

Comment: `the service so the service can call one of the MainActivity's methods` this is bad approach

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that line to the post. I've done it  now. But yes, the Activity is passed with "ACTIVITY" as key, and, in fact, the MainActivity `loadList()` method is called. The Exception is thrown in the line trying to call `findViewById()`.

Comment: you should use bind service and service connection in order to interact with Activity and Service...

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski why? this is a normal callback mechanism when binding local Services

Comment: @calvinfly Providing such callback goes against code modularization. You should use an event or a BroadcastReceiver, since both allow you to send a callback to any Activity listening to them. My example, on the contrary lets only MainActivity receive the callback.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it in wrong way `mActivity = (Activity) intent.getSerializableExtra("ACTIVITY");` is it working?

You can use [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) or [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto) for communicating between Service & Activity

Answer (score 0):

You can use broadcasts to communicate, message handlers, but not this. This is just plain bad practice (and therefore there is no 'good' answer to satisfy you). Not to mention the security issue that your success using this technique would present for Android as a whole (what I am saying here is that this is most likely NOT possible).

You should reconsider being too zealous about maintaining the Serialisation of the Activity, because ultimately you wouldn't be on StackOverflow if it were easy, plus no good programmer can really help you because no good programmer does this.

Comment: Please, read the question I'm making. I ALREADY KNOW, as stated in the post, that this is bad practice. I just want to know why does the activity dies when I do that. Which has already been solved. So please, stop posting "I'm-so-superior-to-you" stuff.

Comment: It's not about being superior to you. It's about helping you. You clearly state you know it's wrong, yet you want to go ahead with it anyway. http://techterms.com/definition/gigo

Comment: I want to go ahead with knowing "why", not with making it that way. However, you say that "it's not good pratice", which I already know, and "there is no satisfying answer", but in the end there is.

Comment: Well you seem to have your answer: serialisation of Android context objects does not work. Plus you found out that the Activity is not actually destroyed. I admit I am confused as to the reason why someone would intentionally write bad code and then publicaly ask why it does not work, but that is your issue.

Comment: With bad practice I was referring to using an activity to send callback, not to serializing an Activity. I did the former intentionally, but not the latter. Moreover, bad practice doesn't mean non-working methods; it means, must-not-do methods. So I didn't write bad code to know why it doesn't work, I wrote unadviseable one.

Answer (score -2):

OK, I got it solved. It happens that, when serializing objects, you don't get the same object in the receiving activity. Both `this`and `mActivity` objects had different IDs.

Comment: Why do you keep on voting down not offering any explanation? Do you think I can learn anything from that?